# how to show no image UIWebImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm uisng UIWebImageView (custom class inherits UIImageView) its working fine, download image from url and show it webview, in some case there is no image in particular url then it show empty space, so need to show there No image, How to find its return image or not.

```
@implementation UIWebImageView

#define kAnimationDuration 0.5

@synthesize animate;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Public Methods

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

        activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        CGFloat xCoord = (frame.size.width / 2.0f) - [activityIndicator frame].size.width;
        CGFloat yCoord = (frame.size.height / 2.0f) - [activityIndicator frame].size.height;
        [activityIndicator setFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, [activityIndicator frame].size.width, [activityIndicator frame].size.height)];
        [activityIndicator setHidesWhenStopped:YES];

        [self addSubview:activityIndicator];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andUrl:(NSURL *)url animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self = [self initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];

        animate = animated;

        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

        if (connection) 
        {
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)downloadImage:(NSURL *)url {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (connection)
    {
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDelegate

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [imageData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    UIImage *downloadedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    if (animate)
    {
        [self setAlpha:0];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animations" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:kAnimationDuration];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        [self setAlpha:100];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
    [self setImage:downloadedImage];

}

- (void)dealloc {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check if `downloadedImage` is not nil, if it's nil show a label with "No Photo" title or show an image with "No Photo".

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    UIImage *downloadedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    if (animate)
    {
        [self setAlpha:0];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animations" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:kAnimationDuration];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        [self setAlpha:100];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
    if (downloadedImage) {
       [self setImage:downloadedImage];
    }
     else {
         // no image downloaded, show "No Image" message
    }

}
```